# Display component based on location name is not working react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show Search bar in other than login page.
This App.js file.... In main I used different component according to the page need.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin) {
     setShowSearchBar(false);
  } else {
     setShowSearchBar(true);
  }

  // location.pathname === '/signin' && setShowSearchBar(false);
}, [userInfo]);
```

in return()

```
<header>
   <Logo />
    {showSerachBar && <SearchBox />}
    <div className="menu">
      <Link className="menu__item link" to="/cart">
        <Cart2 size="24" />
        {cartItems.length > 0 && (
        <span className="badge">{cartItems.length}</span>
         )}
      </Link>
    </div>
</header>
<main></main>
```

I want to show searchbar to the users like registered users other than admin and unregistered users i.e. guest and also I want to hide the searchbar component when user in login page or register page. Here the code hides the searchbar component when user is admin. But in signin page searchbar is not hidden. How to do that. If I use condtional statement to do that like below

```
window.location.pathname === '/signin' ? setShowSearchBar(false) : 
setShowSearchBar(true);
```

It doesn't work. When I check window.location.pathname === '/signin' in browser console, It gives correct answer but when I implement this in code level, it doesn't work.

Comment: If showing the searchBar is predicated solely on userInfo you don't need state at all. Use userInfo directly: `{ userInfo?.isAdmin && <SearchBox /> }`.

Comment: ` window.location.pathname = '/signin' ` use `===`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Sorry. Its typing mistake. When typing code in question.Now I edited. But doesn't work

Comment: @rayhatfield In some cases userInfo is null. That's why I used like that

Comment: I think you're missing my point about not using state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one use `===` there `window.location.pathname = '/signin'`

Adn you can use `useLocation` [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

```
  let location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    location.pathname === '/signin' && setShowSerachBar(false);
  }, [location]);
```

Comment: got an error...TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Comment: Error is resolved by moving <BrowserRouter> to index.js. and I put <App /> in between <BrowserRouter>  tag. And now its working. searchBar component is hidden when pathname is "/signin"

Answer (score 0):

You should never put state set `setShowSearchBar` in render part of the app. Because that fires another render, and so on.

If you want to redirect user to `/signin` you should do it inside `useEffect` for your `userInfo` data. And than in render decide if you want to show `SearchBox`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setShowSerachBar(userInfo.isAdmin);
}, [userInfo.isAdmin]);

return {showSerachBar && <SearchBox />}
```

Comment: Hi sir, its working but In login page It is displayed. I want to hide searchBar component in login page. Search Bar component is placed in header component. So I want to hide that in login page .

Comment: Well in that case if you have some state that you need to share between pages, you should use context to share that value. Post code of your components so that we can have sense of what you want to do

Comment: It is Header component......                                                                          
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin) {
      setShowSearchBar(false);
    } else {
      setShowSearchBar(true);
    }// location.pathname === '/signin' && setShowSearchBar(false);
  }, [userInfo]);  
return(<> <Logo /> {showSerachBar && <SearchBox />} <div lassName="menu">            <Link className="menu__item link" to="/cart"><Cart2 size="24" />{cartItems.length > 0 && (<span className="badge">{cartItems.length}</span>)}</Link></div></>    )

Comment: Can you edit your code in your question and format it nicely

Comment: Sir, I changed question.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with this new code please? I cannot see the question here.